# How can i receive Salesforce Outbound Message from Mule?

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio, salesforce-service-cloud, mule-el

I have use Outbound Message in salesforce. When the Trigger is Occur on the particular object  outbound Message to pass particular End URL. here I want to receive the Outbound Message from the Mulesoft(EndPoint URL) . I have tried HTTP,UDP,TCP,Genric these Kind of endpoint URL but its not working. How i can Use the Mulesoft end point URL. by using Local host its possible or not. Because I have used Localhost:8081 this kind of URL only. what are all the way i have to receive salesforce outbound Message. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The target of the outbound message must be accessible from the web. It has to have some meaningful domain name or IP address (and if you're behind a firewall you need to allow messages from [SF pool of IP addresses](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003652) to pass through).

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_an_Outbound_Messaging_Notification_Service_with_Eclipse_3.2#Testing_Your_Service

> Testing can be a bit of a tricky wicket if you are not developing on a
>   machine that is accessible from the internet. Following the sample, we
>   have deployed our web service to localhost:8080. It is not possible
>   for the salesforce.com servers to make a request to that address.

Comment: But I need to connect with mulesoft how i can connect what are the Endponits i have to use? How i can Use?